# How do I count the number of input elements after h2 element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, count

Let's say I have the following HTML.
In JavaScript, how do I count how many HTML `<input>` I have after `<h2>` element?
In logic way will be 3 and 4, but how can this be done in JavaScript?

```html
<h2>Header Title 1</h2>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<h2>Header Title 2</h2>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
```

Comment: `$(“h4”).find(“*”).count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, one of them could be to count them from the desired node until we reach the end or we come across a node with a different name.

```js
function count_sibling_nodeName_after_element(element, nodeName) {
  var nodeName_counter = 0;
  //use nextElementSibling if only supports recent browsers
  while ((element = element.nextSibling) !== null) {
    //skip (text|comment|document) nodes - useless with nextElementSibling
    if (element.nodeName.indexOf('#') === 0) {
      continue;
    }

    if (element.nodeName === nodeName) {
      nodeName_counter++;
    } else {
      //break to the first element with a different nodeName 
      break;
    }
  }

  return nodeName_counter;
}

var h2_list = document.querySelectorAll('H2');
var h2_list_len = h2_list.length;
for (var i = 0; i < h2_list_len; i++) {
  console.log(count_sibling_nodeName_after_element(h2_list[i], 'DIV'));
}
```

```html
<h2>Header Title 1</h2>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<h2>Header Title 2</h2>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
<div><input data-type="radio" type="radio" name="color" id="black" value="13|1||radio"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this:

```js
var count = document.querySelectorAll('h2>div').length;
```

If you want to get the (3 then 4) as a result
then you can use a different class for each h2 tag you have.

and in js replace h2 with the class name.